# Continuity of a function defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so defined:

$$f(\underline x)= \begin{cases}
\|\underline x\|\left(1-e^{-\frac{||\underline{x}\|^2}{|\underline x_1|}}\right) & \text{if $ x_1 \ne 0$, and} \\ 0 & \text{if $x_1=0$.}\end{cases}$$

How can I prove f is continuous in $\underline 0$?

Comment: What is $\underline{x}$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I think that's the notation for first-order tensors (i.e. vectors), commonly used by physicists. In mathematics, it is more common to write $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Then the definition should read $f(\underline{x})$, I think, and the $\underline{x}_1$ in the exponential term should be simply $x_1$.  @GiulyB: can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The function along the sequence  $\{( \frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt n}, 0,0,...0)\}_{n \in N}$ converges to $-\infty$ ! so it is not continuous.